# Why might a D7 view sorted using random seed always return the same order?

Tags: 7, views

I have a View which displays records for places to eat out, with filters available to narrow things down to pubs, cafes, restaurants etc.   It uses Random Seed sorting, with the aim of providing a list of randomly arranged available places to eat.

The seed is set to use the same seed for every user, and reset the seed every hour.  The site is on Drupal 7.

It all looked suitably random, until I realised that whenever I visited the page, the same random takeaway would be in the top spot.

I tried clearing caches, then removing the sort entirely and putting it back (I thought perhaps the scheduled seed clearance was not happening).  The result order changes when I remove the sort criterion and save, but as soon as I put the random seed sort back in place, there is that one takeaway again, back at the top of the list!  And it's always there.  It was there yesterday too.

Any ideas?  Or does Drupal really like fish and chips a LOT?

Comment: Are you running Views caching, Varnish, or Memcache?

Comment: On this particular view, I have views caching turned off, and I am not running Varnish or Memcache.   I do have Cloudflare caching set up, but I don't think it can be that, because I can see the changes in the view preview as soon as I remove the random seed sort, the order changes before I even save it.  Put the random seed back, and immediately there is that takeaway back at the top of the list.